# How to implement Coroutine queue in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, coroutine

Near the bottom of a continuation [tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Continuation_passing_style) there is a Coroutine implementation that begins with

```
-- The CoroutineT monad is just ContT stacked with a StateT containing the suspended coroutines.
newtype CoroutineT r m a = CoroutineT {runCoroutineT' :: ContT r (StateT [CoroutineT r m ()] m) a}
    deriving (Functor,Applicative,Monad,MonadCont,MonadIO)

-- Used to manipulate the coroutine queue.
getCCs :: Monad m => CoroutineT r m [CoroutineT r m ()]
getCCs = CoroutineT $ lift get

putCCs :: Monad m => [CoroutineT r m ()] -> CoroutineT r m ()
putCCs = CoroutineT . lift . put
```

And then also defines afterwards `dequeue` and `queue` functions using `getCCs` and `putCCs`.

I don't understand how the Coroutine queue is maintained. The type signatures of `getCCs` and `putCCs` don't seem to indicate any type of "variable" maintained inbetween calls. I suspect the state has something to do with `get` and `put` in the implementations of `getCCs` and `putCCs` but I don't know what they are.

Answer (score 1):

A `CoroutineT` is just a wrapper around the monad transformer stack `ContT r (StateT [CoroutineT r m ()] m) a` type.  This essentially means that it's the continuation monad wrapping a state monad where the state type is `[CoroutineT r m ()]`.  The `get` and `put` functions are members of the `MonadState` typeclass, which `StateT` implements.  When you call `lift get`, it has type `(MonadTrans t, MonadState m s) => t m s`.  Since `StateT s` is an instance of `MonadState s`, and `s` in our case is `[CoroutineT r m ()]`, we can plug these in to get

```
lift get
    :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m)
    => t (StateT [CoroutineT r m ()] m) [CoroutineT r m ()]
```

Since `ContT r` implements `MonadTrans`, we can substitute that in and get

```
lift get
    :: (Monad m)
    => ContT r (StateT [CoroutineT r m ()] m) [CoroutineT r m ()]
```

Now if we wrap it in the `CoroutineT` constructor, we get

```
CoroutineT $ lift get
    :: (Monad m)
    => Coroutine r m [CoroutineT r m ()]
```

This is a lot of type wrangling just to say that `CoroutineT $ lift get` is wrapping the `MonadState` `get` function into the `CoroutineT` type.  This is very similar with `putCCs` too.  All these do is get and set the internal state of `[CoroutineT r m ()]`, wrapped up nicely in this monad.  You could use these definitions to make `CoroutineT` an instance of `MonadState [CoroutineT r m]`

```
instance MonadState [CoroutineT r m ()] (CoroutineT r m) where
    get = CoroutineT $ lift get
    put = CoroutineT . lift . put
```

Ideally, you could let `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` do this, but it might not be able to since it's a recursive type definition.